# Change VMWare vSphere Memory Usage Charts to MB or GB

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

Is there a way to set VMWare vSphere Client to show my OS memory usage in MB or GB instead of KB?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen such an option, but you can export the data and import it in Excel.

Comment: Neither have I - So I think this is the best solution.